# Is a shuttle touching the floor of the court not a fault?

Tags: rules, scoring, badminton

I've seen enough badminton matches to know that if, during play, the shuttle falls in my court (probably because I was unable to reach to one side of my court in time), it's my "fault" and the opponent team gets a point and the service.

But, then I was reading [Law 13 - Faults](http://www.worldbadminton.com/rules/#13) in World Badminton. Interestingly enough, they don't cover this case in their list. Here's the complete list for reference:

> If in play, the shuttle:
>
> - lands outside the boundaries of the court (i.e. not on or within the boundary lines);
> - fails to pass over the net;
> - touches the ceiling or side walls;
> - touches the person or dress of a player;
> - touches any other object or person outside the court;
> - is caught and held on the racket and then slung during the execution of a stroke;
> - is hit twice in succession by the same player. However, a shuttle hitting the head and the stringed area of the racket in one stroke shall not be a "fault";
> - is hit by a player and the player's partner successively; or
> - touches a player's racket and does not travel towards the opponent's court;

I couldn't find any reference or metaphors for anything analogous to "touches the floor inside the boundary lines".

Surely, I must be mistaken in interpreting this document. If so, then what is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Law 7.3](http://www.worldbadminton.com/rules/#7) is what you're after:

> The side winning a rally shall add a point to its score. A side shall win a rally, if the opposing side commits a "fault" or the shuttle ceases to be in play because it touches the surface of the court inside the opponent's court.

I believe the reason for the separation here is that a fault is something that you *actively* have to do wrong - hit the shuttle out, touch the net, etc, whereas the shuttle touching the court is a passive action on the part of the team losing the point. For what it's worth, the same distinction applies in volleyball ([Rule 6.1.1](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/documents/FIVB-Volleyball_Rules_2017-2020-EN-v06.pdf)):

> 6.1.1. A team scores a point:
>
> 6.1.1.1 by successfully landing the ball on the opponent’s court
>
> 6.1.1.2 when the opponent team commits a fault;

Comment: I don’t think the reason is really about active vs passive ‘errors’, but who gets the point. Remember that there are _three_ ways to stop the shuttle being in play, corresponding to the three possible point outcomes of a rally: player fault (= point lost by player who commits the fault), floor contact on receiver’s side (= point won by sending side), and let (= no point awarded).